# How come my cipher always only encrypts the first letter correctly but not the second, thrid etc

Tags: javascript, html

So I've been making this Cipher and at the moment if I type in 'a' with a shift of 1 it outputs 'b' which is right but if I put in 'ab' or any other length of string it out puts 'bl' for example. How do I fix this?

```
function encryption(str, amount) {
  var str = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
  var amount = document.getElementById('amountDropdown').value;
  var result = "";
  //loop through each character in word
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var c = str.charCodeAt(i);
    //If the character is uppercase
    if ((c >= 65) && (c <= 90)) {
      result += String.fromCharCode(((c - 65 + amount) % 26) + 65);
    }
    //if the character is lowercase
    else if ((c >= 97) && (c <= 122)) {
      result += String.fromCharCode(((c - 97 + amount) % 26) + 97);
    }
    //if the character isn't a letter
    else {
      result += str.charAt(i);
    }
  }
  //return the result
  outputResult.innerHTML = "The text you have input has been encrypted to.." + result;
}

function decryption() {
  var str = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
  var amount = document.getElementById('amountDropdown').value;
  var result = "";
  //loop through each character in word
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var c = str.charCodeAt(i);
    //If the character is uppercase
    if (c >= 65 && c <= 90) {
      result += String.fromCharCode((c - 65 - amount) % 26 + 65);
    }
    //if the character is lowercase
    else if (c >= 97 && c <= 122) {
      result += String.fromCharCode((c - 97 - amount) % 26 + 97);
    }
    //if the character isn't a letter
    else {
      result += str.charAt(i);
    }
  }
  //return the result
  outputResult.innerHTML = "The text you have input has been encrypted to.." + result;
}

function encryptClickHandler() {
  document.getElementById('inputText').value = encrypt(document.getElementById('inputText').value, document.getElementById('amount').value);
}

function decryptClickHandler() {
  document.getElementById('inputText').value = decrypt(document.getElementById('inputText').value, document.getElementById('amount').value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of an input field is always a string.

When you calculate `(c - 97 - amount) % 26`, you get the following results:

```
c = 97, amount = 1    => (97 - 97 + 1)   % 26 = (0 + 1)   % 26 = 1    % 26 = 1
c = 98, amount = 1    => (98 - 97 + 1)   % 26 = (1 + 1)   % 26 = 2    % 26 = 2
c = 97, amount = '1'  => (97 - 97 + '1') % 26 = (0 + '1') % 26 = '01' % 26 = 1
c = 98, amount = '1'  => (98 - 97 + '1') % 26 = (1 + '1') % 26 = '11' % 26 = 11
```

To fix this, convert the value to an integer:

```
var amount = parseInt(document.getElementById('amountDropdown').value, 10);
```